# Independent Chapters and Unique References

Tags: natbib, subdividing, standalone, import

I am trying to setup a `report` structure so that each author can work on their chapter on their own and once all chapters are finished I can put all together. For this to work well I need each chapter to be completely independent (I was thinking on `standalone` package) and have their own references. Right now I have all chapters being compiled independently, but once I try to integrated them using `import` on the main file it just does not work. I am using `natbib` package.

If anyone have an working example with `natbib` working together with `standalone` and `import` packages, please, share with me! :)

Each chapter should have its own reference file as well!

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! In my opinion, `\include{chapter1}` should work, since the references are maintained, but I am unsure about `natbib` in this case. Perhaps you should give us a starter document that shows your setup

Comment: when this need came up at the american math society, the approach we took was to create an add-on package for `amsbook` that makes certain modifications to the processing of `\chapter` (to allow an author line as part of the chapter heading) and carries that information into the toc.  each author is provided with a copy of the main file that is used to pull all chapters together; an author-specific version contains only one `\include` statement, for that author's chapter.  having a single main file ensures, among other things, that all packages used are compatible.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. After some trials I finally came up with a 'ok' solution. I was trying to setup something like in this [website] (https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Multi-file_LaTeX_projects) . But all worked out nicely when I removed the document class statement for the subfiles `\documentclass[float=false, crop=false]{standalone}` and used just normal document class statement on them like if they were separate files. As a summary, I used `\usepackage{chapterbib}`, `\usepackage[colon, sort&compress]{natbib}` and `\usepackage{standalone}` all together. I will add example later.

Comment: I posted a solution, but it was deleted. Worked for me.

Comment: @DiogoSilva: That wasn't recognizable as solution

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Why not? Does it fail? I'm not really seeing why it isn't recognisable as at least an attempted solution.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Which seems to work, too. @ OP It has been undeleted now. I edited a bit to try to clarify that it is a solution, and added a screenshot. Please feel free to roll back if you wish.

Answer (score 3):

***Introduction copied from author's comment and screenshot added by cfr to try to get this recognised as a solution and undeleted.***

---

After some trials I finally came up with a 'ok' solution. I was trying to setup something like in this website.

But all worked out nicely when I removed the document class statement for the subfiles `\documentclass[float=false, crop=false]{standalone}` and used just normal document class statement on them like if they were separate files.

As a summary, I used `\usepackage{chapterbib}`, `\usepackage[colon, sort&compress]{natbib}` and `\usepackage{standalone}` all together.

## Working solution

The main file (`main.tex`) contains:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage[colon, sort&compress]{natbib}
\setlength{\bibsep}{12pt}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\title{Independent Chapters}
\author{Diogo Silva}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\include{chapter1}
\include{chapter2}
\end{document}
```

The `chapter1.tex` contains:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[colon, sort&compress]{natbib}
\setlength{\bibsep}{12pt}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter1}
Reference \cite{deutsch1992}.
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{./ch01}
\end{document}
```

The `chapter2.tex` contains:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[colon, sort&compress]{natbib}
\setlength{\bibsep}{12pt}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter2}
Reference \cite{journel1999markov}.
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{./ch02}
\end{document}
```

The `ch01.bib` contains:

```
@article{deutsch1992,
title={Geostatistical software library and user’s guide},
author={Deutsch, Clayton V and Journel, Andr{\'e} G},
journal={New York},
year={1992}
}
```

The `ch02.bib` contains:

```
@article{journel1999markov,
title={Markov models for cross-covariances},
author={Journel, AG},
journal={Mathematical Geology},
volume={31},
number={8},
pages={955--964},
year={1999},
publisher={Springer}
}
```

## Output

[image: output (added by cfr)]

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/85301)